# how to pass invalid test data for a login page in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In one of my interview question interviewer asked me how you will pass invalid data for a login page of any application using testng framework in selenium webdriver and I was almost speechless at that time?so any Help?

Comment: Its simple we can send data using sendKeys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testng uses [data providers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) for this behaviour. They can be used when you want to repeat the same test case mutliple times with different parameters.

**Edit**
Just to expand on that, here is an example of how you would set up a DataProvider with invalid login details:

```
@DataProvider
    public static Object[][] loginWrongCreds() {
        Object[][] credentials = new Object[5][2];
        //incorrect login/short login
        credentials[0][0] = "testss"; 
        credentials[0][1] = "testss";
        //empty login
        credentials[1][0] = "";
        credentials[1][1] = "emptylogin";
        //emptypass
        credentials[2][0] = "emptypass"; 
        credentials[2][1] = "";
        //allempty
        credentials[3][0] = "";
        credentials[3][1] = "";
        //incorrect 
        credentials[4][0] = "wrongUname";
        credentials[4][1] = "wrongPass";
        return credentials;
    }
```

The your login test:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "loginWrongCreds", dataProviderClass = LoginPageDataProvider.class)
public void IncorrectCreds(String username, String password) {
  driver().get(LOGIN_PAGE_URL);
  loginPage.loginWrongCreds(username, password);
  AssertJUnit.assertTrue("no message displayed", loginPage_err.isDisplayed());
}
```

Comment: Well thanks,can you explain me @dataProvider means what is "object[][]"

Comment: check out the testng documentation, that explains it pretty well. Its linked above. In short @DataProvider is a testng annotation that supplies data to a test and object is well....an object.

Comment: Well,I want to know which username and password should i pass? Is it valid username & password or it may be invalid username & password.

Comment: In addition to the above answer, TestNG's dataprovider uses a two dimensional array.. in which rows [5] represents the number of times the testcase you want it to be executed while the columns [2] represents the number of arguments you want to pass to your testcase. I hope this gives you a clear idea what dataprovider is doing. 
See below example from the above program. 
Object[][] credentials = new Object[5][2];